# Why does Internal Python Error occur? How to remove it?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using jupyter notebook to import tensorflow 1.12.0. My python version is 3.7.3
The error comes at line :
import tensorflow as tf

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-4ae80da9abf6>", line 2, in <module>
    tf.__version__
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2033, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1095, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 347, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import image
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import distributions
  File "C:\Users\compaq-pc\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core'
```

Comment: How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: At first I upgraded the latest version of pip. Then I installed tensorflow using pip install tensorflow. But it didn`t work. So I`ve installed it using 
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: I see you're using Anaconda; I thought it had its own method of installing packages, separate from pip.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Tensorflow not installed properly,
Follow the below instructions,

```
#Install virtualenv
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
#Create virtual environment name: venv
virtualenv venv
#Activate venv
source venv/bin/activate
#Install tensorflow
venv$ pip3 install tensorflow
#Install Jupyter notebook
venv$ pip3 install notebook
# Launch jupyter notebook
venv$ jupyter notebook
#Verify Installation
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```